# Problem while using Netsieben SSH with System (scp ) command

Tags: c++, ssh, openssh

I am facing some unique problem , not sure how to solve it . I am using the Netsiebin SSH C++ library for connecting with my server . It works perfectly well . I Connected to remote host using SSH2 protocol, with publickey authentication, sent come command to execute at the server  too .

But the problem comes when I started using SCP or rsync  "system( scp or rsync )in between .Its necessary for me to upload some files to server in between and then run Netseiben SSH function again to run that command file at server.But this never happen . Whenever  I use some scp or rsync command and then execute some netseiben function it keeps on waiting and never returns .

Implementation sample:

1. Initialize Netseiben

Ne7SftpSubsystem _sftp;
   ne7ssh *_ssh = new ne7ssh();

2.Connect with Key

```
channel1 = _ssh->connectWithKey ("serverAddress", 22, "userame", "pub key path");
```

3. Send command and read result

```
       _ssh->send ("ls\n", channel1))
       _ssh->waitFor (channel1, "$", 5)
       result = _ssh->read (channel1); //read result
```

1. System function to put some file in server (Which i think is cause for all)

   system( "rsync /home/user/Makefile user@server:~");
   system( "scp /home/user/file.tgz  user@server:~/new");// this Executes
2. Send come command to server (fails here ...This statement never executes)

   ssh->send ("mkdir Tester\n", channel1)

If I dont have the above "system" function to execute some command it works fine .

Is it something to do with Port number . Because at the time of establishing connection I give port number 22
and if I am not wrong scp happens via port the same port which might cause problem . ot sure though
. Have been setting with this for a day . Thanks for your help .